# Vagrant/VirtualBox guest boots only in single processor mode after upgrading Ubuntu guest from 16 to 18

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04

I had a running WEB server with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with LAMP environment. The server is running in a Vagrant/VirtualBox virtual machine. I upgraded it successfully to Ubuntu 16. After that I tried to upgrade it to Ubuntu 18. The upgrade procedure was successful, but after rebooting the VM it hangs in booting with the following last messages:

[image]

If I decrease the number of CPUs to 1 (from the original 2) it boots normally. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Bungicasse I don't want to destroy and build my system from scratch. The mentioned link don't suggest anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VirtualBox set Settings->System->Acceleration->Paravirtualization Interface to "default", we have seen these kinds of problems when it was set to "legacy".